# VSCode custom language extension - Can keywords not be case sensitive

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a custom language extension to colorize syntax for an oddball, little-used language.

In this particular language, keywords and commands are not case sensitive - but the language extension I've created seems to be case sensitive.

Here is an example of a group I called "commands":

```
"commands": {
  "patterns": [
    {
      "name": "keyword.control.wbt",
      "match": "\\b(if|IF|If|iF|then|else|elseif|endif|goto|gosub|exit|return|for|next|while|endwhile|break|drop|errormode|continue|switch|case)\\b"
    }
  ]
},
```

You'll note that I created entries for every possible capitalization of "if", which allowed IF and If to be colorized in the source code I am using to test.

Is there a way to tell VSCode to ignore capitalization?

Comment: There are several other languages with similar requirements, so why not check their grammar files? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/vb/syntaxes/asp-vb-net.tmlanguage.json#L102

Comment: @LexLi Suggest posting this as an answer.

Comment: looking at the link from LexLi, the regex strings in textmate files support setting flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use a RegEX mode to make it case insensitive? For your example, try:

```
"commands": {
  "patterns": [
    {
      "name": "keyword.control.wbt",
      "match": "(?i)\\b(if|then|else|elseif|endif|goto|gosub|exit|return|for|next|while|endwhile|break|drop|errormode|continue|switch|case)\\b"
    }
  ]
},
```

Note that I removed the other variants of `if`

Comment: Oy vey.... I had no idea there were such creatures as RegEx modes. Thanks very much for kindly pointing out the missing piece that was cunningly placed obviously and in plain sight. +100